# Making calls to a Stand-Alone Web API to populate ViewModels in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Lets say I have a standalone ASP.NET Core Web API as its own project (since I don't want to merge it w/ my MVC app)

I now want to create an MVC web application (another project, but same solution) that will make calls to the API. I am aware that for ajax requests I will directly call the API through JavaScript which is straight forward.
However, I am a bit confused as to **how the MVC controller would make calls to the same API to populate the ViewModel and send to the View when a user requests a page i.e. http://myurl/books/1**

I am aware that if I was using something like Angular which is fully client-side I wouldn't be running into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good question. There's three different approaches that I can think of:

- The first is to call the same API from your MVC controller with a HTTPClient object. Might seem a bit weird calling "yourself" on the server side but it works. In my opinion this isn't a great solution, because you're losing type-checking and you'll also making an unnecessary call over the network, and you also have to parse and convert the response back from WebAPI to your .net objects.
- The second approach is to move all of the logic that's inside the API into a new project and compile it all down to a DLL. Your Web Api can then call the code inside the library and your MVC project can do it too. A pretty good approach.
- The third approach is to do what you've suggested - don't populate the Model at all on the server side inside your MVC project and just do it all from the client side. Yes, this will work great with Angular but you can also do this yourself using bog-standard JQuery or Knockout. This approach means much more client side javascript to write (use Typescript!) but you'll end up with a much nicer separation of concerns and cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer! One other question. Can you give me a brief idea of how authentication would work for the API. For example, in an MVC app I just use the built in Identity and let it create the tables. But now before any API calls are made. I am assuming the login form on my MVC app would call the API and the API would return success, then I would set a cookie or something right?

Comment: Authentication for webapi is a big topic - have a read - https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security BTW remember to mark this answer as correct :)

Comment: Second approach while handy for not repeating yourself, will have the effect that calling direct means both applications have to be updated and worked on together which somewhat defeats the point of separating it into it's own WebApi vs having Controllers in your web app.  If it stays as it's own WebApi and called using a client you could update it and provide a versioned Api to allow callers to update on their own schedule.  This may or may not apply to you, and I've gone both ways in the past, but just some food for thought for consideration.

Comment: @Runesun that's a good point - however I would make the point that making the Api public and selling/giving access to the public adds a whole extra level of complication and difficulty.. it's definitely not a simple thing.

Comment: @LachlanB Absolutely.  As with all things in dev, the pros and cons of any approach need to be considered against the context of the problem.